# Sonar runner (ubuntu) execution failed: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sonarqube

I've recently installed SONAR on a Vagrant box running UBUNTU.
Sonar service run fine, but when I try to run the sonar-runner I get an error related to jdbc connector.

I configured sonar to run with mysql database by changing the file "sonar-runner.properties":

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/sonar?seUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
sonar.jdbc.password=sonar
```

When trying to start sonar-runner i get the following output:

```
$ sudo sonar-runner start -e
SonarQube Runner 2.3
Java 1.6.0_27 Sun Microsystems Inc. (64-bit)
Linux 3.2.0-23-generic amd64
INFO: Error stacktraces are turned on.
INFO: Runner configuration file: /home/vagrant/bin/sonar-runner/conf/sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.1.1
13:01:58.363 INFO  - Load batch settings
13:01:59.524 INFO  - User cache: /root/.sonar/cache
13:01:59.560 INFO  - Install plugins
13:02:03.309 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
13:02:03.618 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 43.846s
Final Memory: 2M/14M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:90)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:41)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to connect to database
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1015)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1008)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:766)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:91)
    at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:92)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:74)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1429)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getLogWriter(BasicDataSource.java:1098)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:350)
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.initDatasource(DefaultDatabase.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.persistence.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:75)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1420)
    ... 37 more
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

From my undertanding the jdbc driver is not found. I thought that during initalisation sonar-runner will get the required jar (like it does for other libraries).

I tried to "sudo apt-get install libmysql-java" but still get the same error message.
If that's the right thing to do (which I doubt) I should maybe add the jar to my classpath, but I'm don't know where that jar is actually downloaded and how to add it to the classpath.

Any idea on how to get that solved?

Thanks!!

Comment: Ok I found the mysql.jar under /usr/share/java. Even when added to the CLASSPATH nothing changes..

Comment: I was looking at the wrong place! Issue was not comming from the runner but from SONAR itself.
I had to change de sonar config file '/opt/sonar' and restart it. In the setting page I now can see that sonar is running on mysql. I'm facing a other issue with the runner, but it is not related to the issue above.

So basicaly make sure both SONAR and SONAR-RUNNER are configured to work with mysql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking at the wrong place! 
Issue was not comming from the runner but from SONAR itself. I had to change de sonar config file '/opt/sonar' and restart it. In the setting page I now can see that sonar is running on mysql. 
I'm facing a other issue with the runner, but it is not related to the issue above.

So basicaly make sure both SONAR and SONAR-RUNNER are configured to work with mysql.

Comment: Hello LEM01: can you tell what exactly you changed in /opt/sonar config ?? I am also facing the same issue...

Comment: I'm not using this setup anymore and it's more than a year old.. can't remember sorry. I assume there was some config allowing you to define that sonar and sonar-runner need to talk with mysql and both have to be setup.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Issue was that mysql JDBC connector was not in my bash_profile.
So i add on .bash_profile :

## export jdbc mysql connector to classpath

```
    export CLASSPATH=${HOME}/sonar/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar:$CLASSPATH
```

Hope it could help

Comment: How do I export CLASSPATH in linux ... I actually don't how to use your solution.